# How to save Makefile output in a child directory

Tags: make, makefile

Running `make` in a folder containing a Makefile stores the output files of that Makefile in the same directory. Is it any way to store them in a child directory passing some arguments to the `make` command?

Comment: What do you mean by "save the output files of a Makefile" ?

Comment: It generates binary `.ko` files for some modules, and I would like to know if it is possible to store them in another directory

Comment: You are looking for a "out of tree build" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39015453/building-c-program-out-of-source-tree-with-gnu-make. It has nothing to do with ``sudo`

Comment: Ahh okay ... that is controlled by the content of the Makefile. The makefile contains relations (rules) between files and the commands the builds them, or other files. You will have to redo the makefile with the new file locations, on both sides of the relations. It is just a textfile that you can edit. Remember to take a backup first, in case you break anything. Also you might need to create the directories you want to use, or make a rule for it. Eventually you can update your question with the content of the makefile.

Comment: @SimonSudler the question has nothing to do with `sudo` .. it is all about `make`and makefiles. A relevant question could off course be why at all you need elevated privileges to run make ...

Comment: @SorenA That is what I worte "It has nothing to do with sudo"...

Comment: You are right, I've edited the post. It is just a particular case the use of sudo, nothing to do with what I mean. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @SorenA, that is really useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment, "It generates binary `.ko` files for some modules..." I assume your are trying to build a Linux kernel or module. The Linux kernel supports out of tree build with the `O=` variable:

```
$ cd kernel-source
$ mkdir build
$ make O=build
```

For the kernel you typically don't need `sudo`. It will work without special privileges. For more information see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelTeam/GitKernelBuild.